# Does the tag "data-n-head" negatively affect seo?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers

I have a site I am working on which is built in Nuxt. I believe this tag is Nuxt specific in which case I believe crawlers should ignore.

Here is more info on it: https://midstride.com/seo-for-nuxt-meta-tags/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is on the linked page with...

> Nuxt adds in data-n-head into this but for the most part it’s pretty
>   standard meta tags.

This means that the *tags* are not ignored, however, the data-n-head elements could be.

In the end, the *tags* would not be ignored by search engines and would work as expected.